Highcharts maps : selected state disabled but selected zone anyway colored when viewing in fullscreen
I use Highmaps and doing some external action when user click on a zone of the map.
Everything is working fine but there is an anoying behaviour.
I don't want the selected zone to be highlighted with a separate color so I use the following properties :
allowPointSelect: true,
states: {               
  select: {
    enabled: false,
    color: "#FF0000"
  }
},

You can see the result in the following jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/wtfdc3p2
The strange behavior is :
when I click on a zone the color is not changed (exactly what I want) but when viewing the chart on fullscreen (through the burger menu), the previously zone is colored in red !
Leaving the fulllscreen keep the selected zone in red.
How to disable this colored selection (I tried to make some changes in the render event but unsuccessfully)

Hi, you can set it to the same color as follows: color: this.color https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nsrtq09w/
